# Does removing existing field from protobuf message cause issues?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers, binary-serialization, protobuf-java

I am having one protobuf message -

```
message Sample{
    string field1 = 1;
    string field2 = 2;
    string field3 = 3;
}
```

These messages are stored in datastore in binary format.
So if I want to remove any of the defined field in the above message will it cause any issue in deserialization of the message from datastore?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. Removing fields is fine, although you might want to mark it [reserved](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#reserved) so that nobody reuses it in an incompatible way. New code with old data (with the field) will silently ignore it; old code with new data will just load without the field populated, since everything in `proto3` is implicitly `optional`. This was more of a problem in `proto2`, when `required` was a thing. Another option is to leave the field but mark it with `[deprecated = true]` - it'll still exist and be populated, but some tools will mark the member with the platform-specific obsolete markers for that language/framework.

Comment: Thanks for help. This documentation says the same - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#updating

Comment: @RahulVedpathak Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Could you remove the field, and then reuse the field number at a later time, if you could guarantee that there is no code anywhere that is still assuming the field number refers to the old field?

Comment: @JamesWierzba you'd also need to guarantee that no persisted data (files, cache, databases, etc) uses the old data. Honestly, it just isn't worth the risk. Use a new number.

Comment: added a link to reserved fields doc https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#reserved

Answer (score 3):

Adding and removing fields will not cause safety issues as mentioned in the answer from Marc. The only safety you should care about it is to mark the field as `reserved`. This will ensure that no one uses the same field number accidentally in future